# How to implement ImageView to listview row

Tags: android, mysql, listview, textview, imageview

In my listview textview is shown but it is hard for me to implement imageview . I want to place same icon image before text. Please help !!

**//Fun.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fun extends Activity{
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null; 
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String targetmonth;
    int responseCode;
    int listItemCount=0;
    ListView listview ;
// -->  public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.ic};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

// -->      listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(Fun.this, prgmImages));
        new LoadData().execute();

         // listening to single list item on click
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetmonth)).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });


    } 



    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   { 
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
        @Override
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Fun.this, ""," Can you just see your roof...");  
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
            try{

                     listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(Fun.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));


                     this.progressDialog.dismiss();





                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            // HTTP post 
                    try { 
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                        try{
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.1/app/ap.php");

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
                        httppost.setEntity(se); 
                        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                        int timeoutSocket = 3000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent(); 
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //buffered reader
                        try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                is, "iso-8859-1"), 80);
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                        String line = "0";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result = sb.toString();

                        System.out.println("Magu data aagaya"+result);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        try{
                        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject json_data = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                            targetmonth=json_data.getString("targetmonth");
                            al.add(targetmonth); 
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }   
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }  
                     catch (Exception e) {
                            //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }       


            return null; 
        }


    } 




}
```

**//DataAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String targetmonth;
    String img;
    //String targetamount; 
    String[] month;
    //String[] year;
    //String[] amount;
    public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month) {
        this.month = month;
        //this.year = year;
        //this.amount = amount; 
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    } 
    public int getCount() {
        return month.length;
    } 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.targetmonth); 

            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_id); 
        //  holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetamount); 




            if (position == 0) {
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {

            holder.month.setText(month[position]);




    //      holder.img.setImageResource(img[position]);
        //  holder.amount.setText(amount[position]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return convertView;
    } 
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView month;
        ImageView img;
    //  TextView year, amount; 
    }

}
```

//Customgrid.xml  for formating textview and imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
       <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
       </TableRow>
      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic" />


          <TextView 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:text="hello" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:id="@+id/targetmonth" 
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:textStyle="italic"
               android:paddingBottom="5sp" 
               android:paddingRight="5sp" 
               android:paddingTop="5sp" 
               android:layout_gravity="left" 
               android:layout_weight="0.32" 
               android:gravity="left|center" 
               android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
               android:textColor="#ffc844">

           </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

//main.xml - listview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
       <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
       </TableRow>
      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic" />


          <TextView 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:text="hello" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:id="@+id/targetmonth" 
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:textStyle="italic"
               android:paddingBottom="5sp" 
               android:paddingRight="5sp" 
               android:paddingTop="5sp" 
               android:layout_gravity="left" 
               android:layout_weight="0.32" 
               android:gravity="left|center" 
               android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
               android:textColor="#ffc844">

           </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will not go trough all that code so please explain were your problem is and what is happening or not happening.

Comment: See i want to see imageview and textview in my list activity
in Fun.java textview is extracted from mysql server but i want constant  imageview icon to place left of the textview.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your customgrid.xml with code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_id"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/targetmonth"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:paddingRight="5sp"
                android:paddingTop="5sp"
                android:text="hello"
                android:textColor="#ffc844"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
LazyAdapter.java
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; song = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

use this following link try it http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/